# NoSuchMethodException in MaxMind GeoIp dependency jackson-databind built with mvn shade

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jackson, maxmind

I'm trying to run MaxMind's geoIP in a spark task, but I'm getting a NoSuchMethodException from a maxmind call to a jackson-databind library. I've removed all other versions of jackson-databind using mvn exclusions, yet the error persists after a mvn clean. What am I missing?

No dependency conflicts:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ sift-etl ---
[INFO] com.sift.etl:sift-etl:jar:0.1.6
[INFO] \- com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.maxmind.db:maxmind-db:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0:compile`

Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/List;)V
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeArray(Decoder.java:272)`

Edit: I have a ton of `org.codehaus.jackson`, do I need to exclude these as well? How can I resolve the differences in namespaces?

Edit: This is built into a scala based project that runs in Apache Spark. The jar is compiled into a shaded jar using maven-shade-plugin 2.4

Edit: 
Here's the complete output for jar tvf on the shaded jar:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZVKNsRXgTbeUdEU2ZhM2J3dmc/view?usp=sharing

Here's the result of a grep for jackson-databind:

     `0 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/
   151 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.properties
  5192 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml`

and ArrayNode:
`/usr/lib/jvm/sift-jdk1.8.0_66/bin/jar -tvf target/sift-etl-0.1.6-shaded.jar | grep ArrayNode
 15060 Sat Jan 23 01:33:14 UTC 2016 shaded/parquet/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ArrayNode.class
  1309 Sat Jan 23 01:33:18 UTC 2016 org/apache/lucene/index/DocumentsWriterDeleteQueue$QueryArrayNode.class
  1645 Sat Jan 23 01:33:18 UTC 2016 org/apache/lucene/index/DocumentsWriterDeleteQueue$TermArrayNode.class
 18145 Sat Jan 23 01:33:20 UTC 2016 com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.class
  1058 Sat Jan 23 01:33:22 UTC 2016 org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/XMLPropertyListConfiguration$ArrayNode.class`

Initializing and querying the maxmind GeoIP DB runs successfully in tests. The error only occurs in production when run as a spark task -- after it has been packaged using maven-shade.

maven-shade plugin config: http://pastebin.com/QzrhM5Ee

Is it meaningful that the shaded jar doesn't contain the jackson-databind jar, but all of the *.class files within the jar?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the version of `jackson-databind` in the `spark-assembly.jar`. Here my _-verbose_ trace : `[Loaded org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1 from file:/home/vagrant/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by adding the following relocation to the shaded jar config:

`<relocation>
    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core</shadedPattern>
</relocation>`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue while trying to use Maxmind GeoIP2 with Spark - Scala. Could you elaborate on your solution a bit? Did you recompile Spark with the above shade config or is it something else?

Answer (score 10):

The version of the `ArrayNode` constructor that takes a `JsonNodeFactory` and a `List<JsonNode>` as parameters was removed as of version 2.2.0 of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` jar, so this looks like a bug in the `maxmind-db` library, since it is pulling in version 2.7.0 of `jackson-databind` but (at least indirectly) calling an obsolete method.

If possible, you could try downgrading your `jackson-databind` dependency by explicitly including in your pom file like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It appears to me that this was [added in 2.7.0](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/12e811240e7f492a7a0639730c59c4a0cac10578#diff-ff1cff3f8cbf4dab0ac0fdd2435b1b87R36).

Comment: I stand corrected.  I guess that constructor was *re*added in 2.7.0, as it was [extant in 2.1.0 and then disappeared in 2.2.0](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.java/?v=diff&id2=2.1.0).

Comment: Given that, it seems that despite the maven dependency, that version of `jackson-databind` is not in the classpath of whatever classloader is executing the code in question.

Comment: Hmm, is there any thing else I can provide/debug to find the cause of the issue? I'm kind of at a loss on what else to look at. For what its worth, this is a scala based project and I am trying to use maxmind within an Apache Spark task.

Comment: If you are running a Spark task, does that mean you are preparing a "fat jar" containing all the dependencies?  If so, is version 2.7.0 of the `jackson-databind` jar contained in the fat jar?

Comment: Is a shaded jar the same thing? If so, yes, we are dumping everything into a single "shaded" jar. How does this affect the dependency tree? Mvn still shows no dependency conflicts for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.7.0

Comment: Added more detail regarding the jar in the question.

Comment: Yes, "fat jar", "shaded jar", and "uber jar" are all informally synonymous.  Can you share the result of `jar tvf` on that shaded jar?

Comment: Here's the complete result (10MB): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZVKNsRXgTbeUdEU2ZhM2J3dmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's the result of a grep for jackson-databind:
```
     0 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/
   151 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.properties
  5192 Mon Jan 25 09:53:54 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml
```

Comment: ```jar -tvf sift-etl-0.1.6-shaded.jar | grep ArrayNode

 15060 Sat Jan 23 01:33:14 UTC 2016 shaded/parquet/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ArrayNode.class

  1309 Sat Jan 23 01:33:18 UTC 2016 org/apache/lucene/index/DocumentsWriterDeleteQueue$QueryArrayNode.class
  1645 Sat Jan 23 01:33:18 UTC 2016 org/apache/lucene/index/DocumentsWriterDeleteQueue$TermArrayNode.class
 18145 Sat Jan 23 01:33:20 UTC 2016 com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.class
  1058 Sat Jan 23 01:33:22 UTC 2016 org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/XMLPropertyListConfiguration$ArrayNode.class
```

Comment: Can you also `jar xvf sift-etl-0.1.6-shaded.jar META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml` and inspect that pom to verify that it is indeed version 2.7.0 of `jackson-databind.  Also might help to share the section of your pom where you are configuring the maven shade plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101617/discussion-between-bhan-and-palimpsestor).

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I couldn't get this working with the [`<relocation>` to the shaded jar config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35023302/4448436) or from [downgrading `jackson-databind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959096/4448436), so I ended up just downgrading `com.maxmind.geoip2` as was the latest suggestion from the [Github issue thread](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/issues/57) that led me here, and it worked!

```
<!-- Using an old version b/c https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/issues/57 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
  <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```